# Jquery/Javascript animate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm having a div which width is increased with jquery. I want when that width reaches 100% to do something

```
$(function() {

  $('.play').click(function() {

    $('.loader').animate({
        width: "100%"
    },1500);
    $('.video img').attr('src','css/images/movie-click.jpg')
    $(this).hide();

    if($('.loader').width()==$('.video img').width()) {

        $('.video img').attr('src','css/images/movie.jpg')
    }

});
```

Something is not right in the if statement. if someone can help me. My idea is to check if the with is 100%, and if it is, everything to be back to normal.(play to be showen, width=0%, img attr different.)

Comment: So you want it to show the `movie-click.jpg` during the animation, and after it hide the play button and show the `movie.jpg`?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `complete` callback in [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) to execute code once the animation is finished:

```
$('.play').click(function () {
    $('.loader').animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 1500, function() {
        // any code here will run only after the animation is complete
        $('.video img').attr('src', 'css/images/movie.jpg');   
    });
    // any code here will run as soon as the animation starts,
    // before it's completed
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the click function is only called once, so your if statement is not being ran continuously as it animates.  Instead, simply add that logic to a callback after the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) is complete:

```
$('.loader').animate({
    width: "100%"
},1500,swing, function() {
     $('.video img').attr('src','css/images/movie.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Something is not right in the if statement

Indeed :-) Your current code just compares the css values returned by the two `.width()` calls - which will be false of course.

That's not how you wait for an animation. The animation code is asynchronous, your `animate()` call just starts the animation but returns immediately (and goes on hiding the button and evaluating the condition).

Instead, pass a callback function to [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate), it will be executed when the animation has completed:

```
$(function() {
    $('.play').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();

        var $img = $('.video img');
        $img.attr('src','css/images/movie-click.jpg');

        $('.loader').animate({
            width: "100%"
        }, 1500, function() {
            // executed after the animation
            $img.attr('src','css/images/movie.jpg');
        });
    });
});
```